# Zorin OS displaying black screen and glitchy cursor instead of login screen

Tags: linux, login-screen, mouse-cursor, visual-artifacts, zorin

I have a 2006 MacBook which kept beach-balling after login and I couldn't do anything, so I decided to install Zorin OS.

It is a very good OS and I am enjoying it, but it often has this weird and frustrating glitch: I boot up the MacBook, Zorin OS boots up and gets past the boot screen normally.

But when the login screen appears (or should appear), it just shows a black screen, with my mouse pointer, that when I move it around, spazzes and glitches out! (Note: the login screen is in fact there, judging by the mouse pointer changing to a "hovering on text box" graphic when it is around the password text box, it just doesn't appear in the screen)

So I reset, and same thing. And then after the 3rd or so reset, it boots up as normal! Why does this glitch happen and why does it go back to normal after some resets, but then when I reset after this it happens again? I suspect issues with graphics software/drivers.

Comment: Your situation isn't really clear, but it sounds like there is a hardware problem that made MacOS act up and is now making Zorin act up.  The symptoms you describe are very generic, they could be anything; they aren't characteristic of a specific problem.  You also describe that they happen erratically.  So this would be very hard to diagnose remotely on a Q&A site.  However, one possibility is that the hard drive has some corruption, and that's something easy to check.  Try running fsck and check the SMART stats.  You can probably access fsck in the "advanced" options in GRUB, under recovery.

Comment: Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Zorin OS (I think) and fsck all say the disk is OK. I don't think it's the HDD. What else could it be?